# how to keep a particular column value of a pyspark dataframe after applying groupby function?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe in pyspark :df10 which looks like this: converted_datetime can be different for same 'value'.Ex for value=475 two dates are there 10/04 and 11/04

```
+------------------+---------+-----+--------------------+-------------------+
|        State_name|    type1|value|            lat_long| converted_datetime|
+------------------+---------+-----+--------------------+-------------------+
|     Orange County|Messageid|  475|[33.5509266, -117...|2020-04-10 21:36:10|
|     Orange County|Messageid|  475|[33.5509266, -117...|2020-04-11 21:36:10|
|     Orange County|Messageid|  477|[33.5469206, -117...|2020-04-12 17:05:40|
|     Orange County|Messageid|  477|[33.5469206, -117...|2020-04-12 17:05:40|
|     Orange County|Messageid|  477|[33.5876128, -117...|2020-04-12 17:09:13|
```

By using the below code I am getting df5. I am not sure whether or not **converted_datetime[0:10]**
should be in groupBy because in df5 I am expecting two different dates to be present for a particular 'value'.

```
 df5 = 

 df10.groupBy("value","State_name").agg(F.min("converted_datetime").alias("min"),F.max("converted_datetime").alias("max")) \
                  .withColumn("minUnix", F.unix_timestamp(F.col("min"))) \
                  .withColumn("maxUnix", F.unix_timestamp(F.col("max"))) \
                  .withColumn("duration", F.col("maxUnix") - F.col("minUnix")) \
                  .drop('min','max','minUnix','maxUnix')
+-----+------------------+--------+
|value|        State_name|duration|
+-----+------------------+--------+
|  477|Los Angeles County|     416|
|  481|     Orange County|     419|
|  480|     Orange County|    1220|
|  480|Los Angeles County|     673|
```

The problem is I am loosing the converted_datetime due to groupby function. If I want to keep the datetime value of the corresponding "value" field what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using some value inside `agg` function, it means that there's not one value, but multiple in your dataset (several `converted_datetime` for each `"value", "State_name"` pair that you have). If you want to preserve just any one `converted_datetime` value, you can add it to `agg` arguments with `first` function, to get first value in the group, or `collect_list`/`collect_set` to get all the values in a group.

```
.groupBy("value", "State_name").agg(F.min("converted_datetime").alias("min"), F.max("converted_datetime").alias("max"), F.collect_list(col("converted_datetime")).alias("datetimes"))
```

Comment: I am already using one agg function here. What will be the syntax for the above code snippet  that I provided along with the agg-collect_list?

Comment: @PPARI1 I've updated code sample. Basically just add this function to your `agg` params